# Sidekiq install: ERROR: While executing gem ... (NameError) uninitialized constant RDoc

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install sidekiq on my vagrant virtual machine. This is the error message I recieve when trying to run the command

gem install sidekiq

ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant$ gem install sidekiq
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant RDoc

I have tried opening my gemfile which contains sidekiq: 
gem "sidekiq"
gem 'capistrano-sidekiq' , group: :development

IF this is added to my gemfile it should work right? Or what do i need to do from here?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: gem list 

sidekiq (4.1.4)
sidekiq-status (0.6.0)

ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant$ gem install sidekiq -v 4.1.4
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

Bundle exec sidekiq

That solved the issue